# Django rest framework ordering - set the location of None values

Tags: django, sorting, django-rest-framework

Using Django Rest Framework 'ordering_fields' for allowing sorting by all the model fields.
I've added a new field that allows sorting by, but the requirement is that when sorting ASC - the None values will be first, and when sorting DESC - they will be last. The default behavior seems to be the opposite. 
Is there a quick way to tell the view where I want to put the None values results?

Django version is 2.1.5. Django rest Framework version is 3.7.7

This is part of the model -

```
class Item(models.Model):
    PRIORITIES = (
        ('1', 'Low'),
        ('2', 'Normal'),
        ('3', 'High'),
    )
    identifier = models.IntegerField(default=-1)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    priority = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=PRIORITIES, null=True, blank=True)
```

Part of the view:

```
class ItemViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ordering_fields = tuple(serializer_class.Meta.fields)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you are using the [**OrderingFilter** backend of DRF](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#orderingfilter). This filter backend doesn't come with this ***`null_last`*** or ***`null_first`*** feature. So, we need to create our own filter backend.

```
from rest_framework.filters import OrderingFilter
from django.db.models import F


class CustomOrderingFilter(OrderingFilter):
    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        ordering = self.get_ordering(request, queryset, view)
        def make_f_object(x):
            return F(x[1:]).desc(nulls_last=True) if x[0] == '-' else F(x).asc(nulls_last=True)

        if ordering:
            ordering = map(make_f_object, ordering)
            queryset = queryset.order_by(*ordering)

        return queryset
```

and use this **`CustomOrderingFilter`** class as your filter backend.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': [
        # other default filter backends,
        'dotted.path.to.CustomOrderingFilter'
    ]
}
```

Comment: This is honestly such a beautiful implementation. One tiny nit-pick is that you shouldn't assign lambdas to variables (https://www.flake8rules.com/rules/E731.html), but use a def instead.